# REACT : How can we Upload Image and Input text using Fetch or Axios in a single click function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So basically I'm new to react and couldn't find a single doc or resources regarding uploading an Image and input value at the same time.

One Solution is `Form Data`, But that isn't working as expected

The other method is `Serialize`, But I can't find any doc that explain the way to use in React

So, it would be really great for me and the newbies of React to know about this if you anyone could help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following method you can use multer with express to handle the file data that is been uploaded.

React file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  handleFileChange = e => {
    this.setState({ file: e.target.files[0] });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  };

  upload = () => {
    if (this.state.file) {
      let data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", this.state.file);
      data.set("data", this.state.text);

      axios
        .post("http://yourhost/file", data)
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
        <input type="button" onClick={this.upload} value="Upload" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export defaults App;
```

express server side

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app =express();
    const path = require('path');
    const cors = require('cors')();
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const multer  = require('multer')
    const port =process.env.PORT || 3000;;



    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
       extended:true
    }));

    app.use(cors);

    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: __dirname +'/media/',
      filename(req, file, cb) {
       console.log(file);
       cb(null, `${file.originalname}-${new Date()}`);
      }
    });

    const upload = multer({ storage });

    app.post('/file',upload.single('file'), function(req, res) {
      console.log(req.body.data);
      console.log(req.files);
    });

   app.listen(port,()=> console.log('Running on port: '+port));
```

Comment: Should'nt we use URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]) ?

Comment: @bharathi no need to do that you can use formdata

Comment: WOW , IT WORKS LIKE A CHARM , YOU ARE GREAT

Comment: It helped me too :) . But can you tell me what is ( .append("file") & (.append("data") ? Can we name it anything ? or is it specifc for formdata ?

Comment: @ThanveerShah yes you can name it anything append() takes 2 parameters 1st one is the **key** and the other is the **value**.