# Submit React form with multiple text input and image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So, from this link [REACT : How can we Upload Image and Input text using Fetch or Axios in a single click function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613586/react-how-can-we-upload-image-and-input-text-using-fetch-or-axios-in-a-single) , i learn how to submit form with text + images, but it only contains 1 text input, from my case, i have multiple text input, How i submit multiple text input with formData ? i tried use Object, but it cannot be use on server side.

Edit: So i got it using this, but is there a way to send the whole object directly?

```
async function submitForm() {
    const formdata = new FormData(); // for adding form files i guess
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formdata.append("files", files[i], files[i].name); // "name", files, filename
    }
    for (let key in inputs) {
      formdata.append(key, inputs[key]);
    }

    const response = await axios.post("/games", formdata);
    const { data } = response;
    console.log(data.message);
  }
```

here is my code

```
const AddForm = ({ getData, classes }) => {
  console.log("Rendering AddFORM");
  const [checkboxes, setChecked] = React.useState([]);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({});
  const [files, setFiles] = React.useState(null);
  const history = useHistory();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setInputs({ ...inputs, platform: checkboxes });
  }, [checkboxes]);

  const onChangeForField = React.useCallback(({ target: { name, value } }) =>
    setInputs((state) => ({ ...state, [name]: value }), [])
  );
  const onChangeForFiles = ({ target: { files } }) => setFiles(files);

  const handleCheck = ({ target: { value } }) => {
    checkboxes.includes(value)
      ? setChecked(checkboxes.filter((item) => item !== value))
      : setChecked([...checkboxes, value]);
  };

  async function submitForm() {
    const formdata = new FormData(); // for adding form files i guess
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formdata.append("files", files[i], files[i].name); // "name", files, filename
    }
    formdata.set("data", inputs);
    const response = await axios.post("/games", formdata);
    const { data } = response;
    console.log(data.message);
  }

  return (
    <Paper
      elevation={2}
      style={{ padding: "1rem", width: "70%", margin: "0 auto" }}
    >
      <form>
        <Typography variant="h5" color="initial">
          Add a new game
        </Typography>
        <TextField
          required
          id="standard-required"
          name="title"
          label="Title"
          fullWidth
          placeholder="Game title"
          margin="normal"
          onChange={onChangeForField}
        />
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          multiline
          required
          id="standard-required"
          name="description"
          label="Description"
          placeholder="Description"
          margin="normal"
          onChange={onChangeForField}
        />
        <FormControl margin="normal" fullWidth>
          <FormLabel component="legend">Select Platforms</FormLabel>
          <FormGroup row>
            {platforms.map((p, idx) => (
              <FormControlLabel
                key={idx}
                control={
                  <Checkbox name="platforms" onChange={handleCheck} value={p} />
                }
                label={p}
              />
            ))}
          </FormGroup>
        </FormControl>
        <FormControl>
          <Button variant="contained">
            <label htmlFor="file-upload">Upload Files</label>
          </Button>

          <input
            type="file"
            multiple
            id="file-upload"
            name="images"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
            onChange={onChangeForFiles}
          ></input>
        </FormControl>
        <div className={classes.ButtonsContainer}>
          <Button
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            onClick={async (e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              await submitForm();
              getData();
              // history.push("/");
            }}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
          <Button variant="contained" color="secondary">
            <Link to="/">Go Back</Link>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Paper>
  );
};
```

server side route

```
app.post(
  "/games",
  upload.array("files"),
  wrapAsync(async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.files);
```

got [object Object] on server side, looks like it cannot parse this.

Thanks before

Comment: I can't see your submit  function? I mean in "onSubmit"

Comment: is submitForm() , sorry if my code is confusing

Comment: You need to put that function in the form tag. Not the button tag.

Comment: oh you mean onSubmit={submitForm}, ok gonna do that later. btw i already got it, see my edits on top, but it is possible to send object directly without appending new keys